# Why is a phone number required in gae?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

My gae python code seems to require these if statements. Without them gae throws this error.

```
raise exception('%s must not be empty.' % name)
BadValueError: phone must not be empty.
```

This is the code.

```
reservation = Reservations(parent=court) 
if phone:
    reservation.phone = phone
if email:
    reservation.email = email
reservation.put()
```

This is the datastore model. There is no "Required".

```
class Reservations(db.Model):    #parent is Courts
    court = db.ReferenceProperty(Courts)
    phone = db.PhoneNumberProperty()
    email = db.EmailProperty()
```

Why are phone and email required in my code?

Comment: I really wouldn't recommend using the 'semantic' properties such as `PhoneNumberProperty` and `EmailProperty`. They're poorly supported and do very little validation, so they don't really add anything over just using a `StringProperty`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing without the if statements your code looks like this:

```
reservation = Reservations(parent=court) 
reservation.phone = phone
reservation.email = email
reservation.put()
```

If that's so then most likely it will throw that exception cause maybe the `phone` in your case is an empty string or something that doesn't look like a phone when you're assigning to `reservation.phone`.

I would suggest you though not use the `PhoneNumberProperty` and `EmailProperty` at all, since they were [dropped](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties) in the newest NDB and instead you can use `StringProperty`. Consider switching to NDB if it's a new project, because of some cool new features, like [automatic caching and more](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/).

Comment: The above issue is why I abandonded using PhoneNumberProperty, EmailProperty ...   You can't have empty "" values with any of them, which is a pain, if you don't want them required.

Comment: @TimHoffman That's not a bad reason to abandon them and I think this was one of the reasons, among others, that Google didn't include them in the newest version (ndb).